# what does this error mean - installing perl module with cpan

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I tried to install [HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilderX%3a%3aASP_NET) with `cpan` on Windows 7.
I have strawberry perl setup.

Everything went smoothly until the end when I got the following. Is this something I should worry about?

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/10-traits.t    (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2-3
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 5 tests but ran 3.
t/boilerplate.t  (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   1-2
Files=7, Tests=22,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr +  0.01 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/7 test programs. 2/22 subtests failed.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  ECARROLL/HTML-TreeBuilderX-ASP_NET-0.09.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ECARROLL/HTML-TreeBuilderX-ASP_NET-0.09.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 ECARROLL/HTML-TreeBuilderX-ASP_NET-0.09.tar.gz: make_test NO
```

then when installing WWW::Mechanize
I got

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\local\back.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 47 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  33
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t\local\click_button.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 19 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   15-17, 19
Files=52, Tests=550, 247 wallclock secs ( 0.42 usr +  0.28 sys =  0.70 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/52 test programs. 1/550 subtests failed.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  JESSE/WWW-Mechanize-1.70.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports JESSE/WWW-Mechanize-1.70.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 JESSE/WWW-Mechanize-1.70.tar.gz              : make_test NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you that some tests failed and therefore the install will not proceed. The failed tests are in `t/10-traits.t` and the failed tests are 2 and 3. Whether you should worry about this depends on what the tests are and why they are failing.

These are the failing tests:

```
eval { HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET->new_with_traits( traits => ['htmlElement'] ) };
ok ( !$@, 'htmlElement trait construction is good!!' );

eval {
    HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET->new_with_traits( traits => ['htmlElement'] );
    HTML::Element->new('a', href => "__doPostBack('foo','bar')" )->httpRequest;
};
like ( $@, qr/<form>/, 'Success with use! (failed without the parent form)' );
```